# How cast an interface object to a specific inherited object

Tags: c++, class, c++11, casting, type-conversion

I have an interface Class :

```
Class IOperand
{
    virtual ~IOperand() {};

    virtual std::string  getType() const = 0;
}
```

And i have several inherited Class like this one :

```
class Int8: public IOperand
{
    public:
      Int8(int8_t _value = 0);
      virtual ~Int8() {};
      virtual std::string getType() const;

      int8__t  getValue() const;

    private:
      int8_t _value
}
```

I use pointer on IOperand type, but i need to use the getValue() member function.
How can I cast an IOperand type object in a sub-class type object depending of the return of getType() (which return a string contaning the name of the target sub-class.) ?

Answer (score 5):

You are asking to cast a base type to a derived type. Usually this kind of casting is a sign of a poor design, since -- in most cases -- the base type should provide a virtual method that provides the desired operation. However, in some cases, it is necessary to cast to a specific class. There are really two ways to do this.

**Unknown runtime type**
If you do not know whether the type is or is not an Int8, then you need a polymorphic down cast. This is done with the special `dynamic_cast` mechanism like this:

```
IOperand* operand = // ...
Int8* casted = dynamic_cast<Int8*>(operand);
if (casted == nullptr) {
   // runtime type was not an Int8
   return;
}
// operate on casted object...
```

**Known runtime type**
If you absolutely know for certain that the type is the subtype, then you probably want to use a `static_cast`. Note, however, that a `static_cast` won't do the checking that `dynamic_cast` does. It will, however, be significantly faster to do a `static_cast`, since it doesn't require any reflection or walking the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 1):

See Wikipedia's [Run-time type information article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_Type_Information#C.2B.2B_Example):

```
/* A base class pointer can point to objects of any class which is derived 
 * from it. RTTI is useful to identify which type (derived class) of object is 
  * pointed to by a base class pointer.
  */

 #include <iostream>

 class Base
 {
 public:
     Base() { } 
     virtual ~Base() { } 

     virtual void hello() 
     {
         std::cout << "in Base";
     }
 };

 class Derived : public Base
 {
 public:
     void hello() 
     {
         std::cout << "in Derived";
     }
 };

 int main()
 {
     Base* basePointer = new Derived();
     Derived* derivedPointer = NULL;

     //To find whether basePointer is pointing to Derived type of object
     derivedPointer = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePointer);

     if (derivedPointer != NULL)
     {
         std::cout << "basePointer is pointing to a Derived class object"; //Identified
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout << "basePointer is NOT pointing to a Derived class object";
     }

     //Requires virtual destructor 
     delete basePointer;
     basePointer = NULL;

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dynamic_cast<>:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

You can compare the strings and write if/else to cast the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
IOperand *op = function_returning_ioperand_pointer();

if (op->getType() == "Int8") {
    Int8 *int8_op = dynamic_cast<Int8*>(op);
    if (!int8_op) std::cerr << "Cast failed" << std::endl;
}
```